# How to advance through an array of JObjects one at a time with each button click

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a question about JObjects in JSON.NET. I get an ID from my Json. And now I want to show the next ID from the JSON on a label when I click on a button. That works, but when I click on the button again it doesn't go to the next ID. Let us suppose that I have six IDs. Whenever I click on the button I always  want it to go to the next ID.

Here is my code:

```
private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyProperty);

    string user = MyProperty;
    //lbuser.Content = json;

    //string tan = "";
    MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
    // main.alpha = tan;

    string html = string.Empty;
    string url = @"http://aa.worloud.at/?tag=question&token=" + Property;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    // dynamic magic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(html);
    // string json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(html);


    var j = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(user) as Dictionary<string, object>;
    var d = j["data"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
    lbuser.Content = d["fname"] + " " + d["lname"].ToString();

    JObject QuestionObject = JObject.Parse(html);
    JToken question = QuestionObject["data"].First["q_text"];
    lbquestion.Content = question;


    JObject IDObject = JObject.Parse(html);
    JToken id = IDObject["data"].First["q_id"];
    JToken lastid = IDObject["data"].Last["q_id"];
    //JToken nextid = IDObject["data"].First["q_id"];
    lbid.Content = "Frage " + id + " von " + lastid;
}

class qq
{ 

}

private void bt_no_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string html = string.Empty;
    string url = @"http://aa.worloud.at/?tag=question&token=" + Property;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    JObject IDObject = JObject.Parse(html);
    JToken nextid = IDObject["data"].First.Next["q_id"];
    //int result = (int)nextid;
    lbid.Content = nextid;
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is a console app which will hopefully make it more clear what I am trying to do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"{""data"":[{""q_id"":""1"",""q_text"":""banana.""},{""q_id"":""2"",""q_text"":""apple.""}, {""q_id"":""3"",""q_text"":""mango.""},{""q_id"":""4"",""q_text"":""strawberries.""}],""tag"":""question"",""error"":null}";

    JObject IDObject = JObject.Parse(json);
    JToken fruit = IDObject["data"].First["q_text"];
    Console.WriteLine(fruit);

    // I do not know how to do a button click on a console Application, 
    // but this line should be in a button event.  And when I click on 
    // the button it should always show the next fruit: first click apple,
    // second click mango, etc., until the end.
    JToken nextfruit = IDObject["data"].First.Next["q_text"]; 

    Console.WriteLine(nextfruit);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: There's no indication in the code posted of a button click. If the code is within a button click handler, well, you're parsing the JSON with every click. How would the code know what the "next ID" is?

Comment: I edited my question so it looks like

Comment: Ok i edited my question now there are a console Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an `IEnumerator<JObject>` from the `data` array at load time and store it into a class-level variable.  Then, on each button click, call `enumerator.MoveNext()` on the enumerator and get next `JObject` from the `enumerator.Current` property.  From there you can get the `q_text` and display it.

I'm not sure what platform you are building for, so here's a console application to demonstrate the concept.  I'll use keypresses to simulate the button clicks.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyForm form = new MyForm();

        form.LoadJson();

        while (form.HasNext)
        {
            // simulate button click with a keypress
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            form.ButtonClick();
        }
    }
}

public class MyForm
{
    private IEnumerator<JObject> Enumerator { get; set; }
    public bool HasNext { get; private set; }

    public void LoadJson()
    {
        string json = @"{""data"":[{""q_id"":""1"",""q_text"":""banana.""},{""q_id"":""2"",""q_text"":""apple.""}, {""q_id"":""3"",""q_text"":""mango.""},{""q_id"":""4"",""q_text"":""strawberries.""}],""tag"":""question"",""error"":null}";

        JObject IDObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        Enumerator = IDObject["data"].Children<JObject>().GetEnumerator();
        ButtonClick();  // Advance to first fruit
    }

    public void ButtonClick()
    {
        HasNext = Enumerator.MoveNext();
        if (HasNext)
        {
            JObject nextfruit = Enumerator.Current;
            Console.WriteLine(nextfruit["q_text"] + "  Press any key to advance to the next fruit.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No more fruits.");
        }
    }
}
```

Output (each line appears one at a time as you press a key):

```
banana.  Press any key to advance to the next fruit.
apple.  Press any key to advance to the next fruit.
mango.  Press any key to advance to the next fruit.
strawberries.  Press any key to advance to the next fruit.
No more fruits.
```

Comment: Thank you the Console Apllication is working but how I do this code line : Console.WriteLine(nextfruit["q_text"] with a label on wpf?

Comment: Try something like this: `label.Content = (string)nextfruit["q_text"];`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I tried it before it came the error The type string can not be implicity converted to System.Windows.Controls.Label

Comment: In that case, you should open a new question asking about that part.  Show your code and your XAML, and be sure to tag it `wpf` and `c#`.